# PHP 404 on assets

Tags: php, html

index.php

```
404
```

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://localhost:5000/
```

https://localhost:5000/doesntexist

```
404
```

https://localhost:5000/doesntexist.png

```
<!doctype html><html><head><title>404 Not Found</title><style>
body { background-color: #fcfcfc; color: #333333; margin: 0; padding:0; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; font-weight: normal; background-color: #9999cc; min-height:2em; line-height:2em; border-bottom: 1px inset black; margin: 0; }
h1, p { padding-left: 10px; }
code.url { background-color: #eeeeee; font-family:monospace; padding:0 2px;}
</style>
</head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource <code class="url">/doesntexist.png</code> was not found on this server.</p></body></html>
```

I want all files to be send to index.php, including images and other assets.

I can't find any answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to create a `.htaccess` file in your root folder and add this to it, assuming you run Apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule allows authentication to work with fast-cgi
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [NC,L]

# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond $0::%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^:]*+(?::[^:]*+)*?)::(/.+?)\1$
RewriteRule .+ - [E=BASE:%2]
RewriteRule .* %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```